# File upload in Meteor App

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have found lots of different information, but some packages are deprecated now. Many answers were posted more then 2 years ago

I want to upload photos from backend-panel (so, no user-uploads), photos are for products in e-commerse site. Planning to deploy to digital ocean (or something like that).

So what is the **correct way** to handle photos upload in Meteor application in my situation?

thank you for your answers!

Comment: I really recommend a package https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend [Slingshot](https://atmospherejs.com/edgee/slingshot). It's not depreciated, and it's really easy to use.

It's also a great idea because it doesn't take up your server's resources by uploading photos directly to it. As well as the easy use of a storage service like S3 so you don't have to worry about backups or partitioning big enough hard drives.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I really want to know is this package able to handle heavy loads, let's say in e-commerce site with thousands of photos? (and tens of thousands requasts a day)

Comment: Well you would only use that package to upload new or changed photos. Once they are uploaded you would use the S3 URL to access them in your code. S3 can definitely handle tens of thousands of requests. Unless I'm mistaken, I don't think you will be uploading tens of thousands of times a day. But I would think this package could handle very frequent uploads. Once it's configured, you can just start sending them as fast as you need.